# Homework help: User-made List output

Tags: c++, list, user-defined-functions

This is homework help. I've been given a simple card dealing program, and I've been given the task to make a list class that can record the ranks that are drawn per suit. The problem that I am having right now is my output. I've put the ranks through a loop that iterate for each suit, and after a stop card is hit, the loop stops and I have to output what cards were drawn from each suit.

My output function looks like this.

```
void list::Output(){
  while(curr!=NULL){
  cout << curr->data;
  curr = curr->next;
  }
}
```

This is one of the loops that puts the strings into one of the lists.

```
list Deck[4];
if (suit2 == suit[0]){        //suit2 is the suit of the current card
   for (int i=0;i<13;i++){    //suit is a const string array provided by the teacher
      if (rank2 == rank[i])   //rank2 is the current rank, rank is the const string
         Deck[0].Input(i);
   }
}
```

When I call the output function, it seems to work fine. That is, until I attempt to add an endl; after it or add any kind of std output with it. When I try to do that, the output gets all spaced out and weirdly formatted.

For example, when I simply write

```
Deck[0].Output();
```

It compiles fine, and outputs fine, like this:

```
 King Jack 8 Jack 6 Ace%
```

But when I add an endl after it:

```
Deck[0].Output();
cout << endl;
```

It compiles fine, but outputs like this:

```
King



Jack
8



Jack




6
Ace
```

What could be causing this? It's extremely frustrating.

Comment: It's hard to help with only the code you have provided. I would step through the output with a debugger looking at curr->data before the cout

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something like

```
if (rank2 == rank[i])
    Deck[0].Output(i);
    cout << endl;
```

then realize that `cout << endl;` is executed unconditionally; the indentation is misleading. Make it

```
if (rank2 == rank[i]) {
    Deck[0].Output(i);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Note the pair of braces.

Comment: I'm doing Deck[0].Input(i)

Comment: I am inputting the ranks into the lists, then attempting to output the lists with formatting.

Comment: You said, and I quote: "For example, when I simply write 'Deck[0].Output();' ...". So which way is it? It doesn't matter though. The point is, only one statement following an `if` is executed conditionally. Use braces to group multiple statements into a single block.